# Correct usage of MouseDragElementBehavior

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my MainWindow I have defined a region, that I am injecting my UserControls into (using Prism, but it doesn't matter). My control should be resizeable (it works perfectly) and moveable. To drag and move my user control I am using Blend's MouseDragElementBehavior. Problem is, that although my control moves, when I resize MainWindow it gets cut :

When I am not moving my control everything works, as expected, when I resize MainWindow scrollBar shows up:

[image]

But when I move my user control to the bottom of the MainWindow, the ScrollBar is not showing up like it does't know, that my control has been moved:

[image]

Important: The ScrollBar is showing up in both scenarios at exact same time, though when I move my user control down it should appear  much more sonner, when I reach the bounds of the user control.  On the picture below  you can see the moment when the ScrollBar is showing up after I  draged my control down. It appeared too late, control gets cut.
[image]

It's hard to explain, let me know if you understood me correctly.

My code:

```
<Window x:Class="ViewInjection.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Click="Button_Click">Add View</Button>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition   Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>                                               
                        </Grid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

UserControl:

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViewInjection.Views"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" x:Class="ViewInjection.Views.ViewA"
             mc:Ignorable="d">   


    <Border  x:Name="Border" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#FF626161" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="200">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ei:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="true"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <DockPanel x:Name="sizableContent" Background="LightGray" Focusable="False" LastChildFill="True" MinHeight="300" MinWidth="300">


            <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" >
                <!--Make user control resizeable-->
                <Thumb DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,1,1"
                   DragDelta="OnResizeThumbDragDelta" 
                   DragStarted="OnResizeThumbDragStarted" 
                   DragCompleted="OnResizeThumbDragCompleted">
                    <Thumb.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                            <Style.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Grid x:Name="resizeVisual" DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  >
                                                <Line X1="6" Y1="18" X2="18" Y2="6" Stroke="DarkGray" StrokeThickness="1.5"/>

                                                <Line X1="10" Y1="18" X2="18" Y2="10" Stroke="DarkGray" StrokeThickness="1.5"/>
                                                <Line X1="14" Y1="18" X2="18" Y2="14" Stroke="DarkGray" StrokeThickness="1.5"/>

                                                <Grid.Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeNWSE"/>
                                                            </Trigger>
                                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </Grid.Style>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style.Setters>
                        </Style>
                    </Thumb.Style>
                </Thumb>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Button Margin="12" Width="75" TabIndex="1" Content="Ok"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>

            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="16,16,16,4">
                <TextBlock Text="My UserControl"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

P.S.

I am using items control to have multiple controls within that region. I am using Grid as a template, because I want controls to overlap each other.

Comment: I believe in this scenario you'll need to listen for size changes via `SizeChangedEventArgs` and then fire off `updateLayout()` for another measure/arrange pass. Left as comment since no time to test. :)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW., that;s reasonable. Could you be more specific though?  Size changes of what? Parent grid?